# How to make inputs of a row at the same line vertically with the inputs of the next row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, input

I am making a member registration form and I want to make or set inputs of a row at the same line vertically with the inputs of the next row. I made a display:flex div and put inside it the inputs that I want them inline, but I couldn't set them at the same line vertically with the inputs of the next row.

I am trying to get it like this
https://i.ibb.co/SscFZvw/reg.png

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/67bh94g7thmfl8h/bootstrap.css" />
<link href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/dfc2odz62i3h6zx/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/8b5z3fkk887injx/megamenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1" style="margin: 0 auto;width:100%">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Member Registration</div>
        <br>
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/member_reg" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <div style="display:flex;">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('membership_date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Membership Date</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="membership_date" value="{{ old('membership_date') }}" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('membership_no.') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Membership No.</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="membership_no." value="{{ old('membership_no.') }}" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div style="display:flex;">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('member_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Member Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_name" value="{{ old('member_name') }}" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('father_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Father Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="father_name" value="{{ old('father_name') }}" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('mother_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Mother Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mother_name" value="{{ old('mother_name') }}" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div style="display:flex;">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('birth_date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Birth Date</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="birth_date" value="{{ old('birth_date') }}" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('birth_place') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Birth Place</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="birth_place" value="{{ old('birth_place') }}" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('gender') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Gender</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gender" value="{{ old('gender') }}" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap, why not use bootstrap columns? Like `col-sm-6` in a div wrapped around each set of label/inputs?

Comment: The markup is all messed up and doesn't respect Bootstrap's grid system. This will help you - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-row

Comment: That's what I mean, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great use case for CSS grid, if you don't need to support IE11 (you can still use grid with IE10+ but it's just more work). See below, if you remove your flex containers and then just turn your form into a 3 column grid container it will work as intended (see the style tag at the end of body). Note that I added an empty placeholder div to create that whitespace on the first row.

```css
.form-horizontal {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px
}
```

```html
<head>
  <html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/67bh94g7thmfl8h/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/dfc2odz62i3h6zx/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/8b5z3fkk887injx/megamenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  </head>
</html>
<body>     
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1" style="margin: 0 auto;width:100%">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Member Registration</div>
          <br>
          <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/member_reg" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  
            <!-- <div style="display:flex;"> -->
              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('membership_date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Membership Date</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="membership_date" value="{{ old('membership_date') }}" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
  
              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('membership_no.') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Membership No.</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="membership_no." value="{{ old('membership_no.') }}" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- ADD EMPTY DIV PLACEHOLDER -->
              <div class="placeholder_item"></div>
            <!-- </div> -->
  
            <!-- <div style="display:flex;"> -->
              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('member_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Member Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_name" value="{{ old('member_name') }}" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
  
              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('father_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Father Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="father_name" value="{{ old('father_name') }}" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
  
              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('mother_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Mother Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mother_name" value="{{ old('mother_name') }}" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
            <!-- </div> -->
  
            <!-- <div style="display:flex;"> -->
              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('birth_date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Birth Date</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="birth_date" value="{{ old('birth_date') }}" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
  
              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('birth_place') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Birth Place</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="birth_place" value="{{ old('birth_place') }}" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
  
              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('gender') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Gender</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gender" value="{{ old('gender') }}" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
            <!-- </div> -->
  
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Although this solves the problem, it also defeats the purpose of OP using Bootstrap